Dynamic hide/display columns - PowerBI Dax
I'm working with a table that has about 20 calculated measures being displayed.  We have slicers to change the summaries but the empty results are messing up with the visual. I was wondering if it is possible to hide the columns with 0 amount dynamically, as the values will change according to the slicers.

The end result is similar to the one using the "New parameter: field", with the difference that I dont want the user to be able to change anything, if the column is empty it should not be displayed.
Thank you for your attention folks!
